# Find the $cot^{-1}(x)$ series without using the Taylor series????

Tags: calculus

Find the $cot^{-1}(x)$ series without using the Taylor series?

Comment: There are many different ways to compute the series expansion. And in this case the Taylor expansion does not exist because the function is singular at x = 0; the expansion starts with 1/x.

Comment: @CountIblis: $\operatorname{arccot}{0} = \pi/2$, for example.  It is the cot function that is infinite at $0$.

Comment: I see, not yet fully awake I guess :) .